# Resharper C++ - scan entire solution for issues

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper

I have a VS2013 solution with several projects- some in C# and some in C++.

When i use resharper->inspect->find issues in solution

It only shows issues from C# projects.

But when i open some cpp file, i can see the different issues in it.

How can I scan an entire project/solution for C++ issues?

Comment: you could read this:
http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Code_Analysis__Fix_in_Scope.html#d6948e2809

Comment: Do you have ReSharper C++ installed? If so, and it's not finding issues that are in cpp files (and that are resharper warnings, not the compiler), then please raise an issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com